# How to make Django OneToOneField mutually exclusive across classes

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have: myARecord = models.OneToOneField(ClassA,...) that is used by two different classes, B and C.

In the Django admin, it lets me create a B record and a C record that both reference the same A record. Two instances of either B or C cannot reference the same A record as expected.

How do I enforce that mutual exclusivity for all records of both B and C classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `OneToOneField` is basically a foreign key with `unique=True` set, which means:

1. because it is a foreign key, the instance that it is referencing can be referenced by other instances that have it as a foreign key value as well
2. `unique=True` means that the value should be unique throughout the table, meaning that two instances of model `ClassB` cannot have the same foreign key value to the pointing to `ClassA`, but one instance of `ClassB` can have the same foreign key value to the `ClassA` model as one instance of `ClassC` and so forth

That being said, enforcing a strict one-to-one relationship this way can be done only between two tables, not three. In that case you could create some custom validation, for example:

```
class ClassB(models.Model):
    a_reference = models.OneToOneField(ClassA)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        class_c_instances_with_same_value = ClassC.objects.filter(a_reference=self.a_reference)
        if class_c_instances_with_same_value:
            raise ValidationError
        super(ClassB, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

but you would have to do that for all your classes. Maybe create a mixin class and use that one in all classes where you want to enforce this.

Note: As [Kevin Christopher Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2395796/kevin-christopher-henry) pointed out in the comments, you might wanna keep your validations in the [`clean()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/).

Comment: Good answer, but the validation should go in `clean()`, not `save()`.

Comment: It might be a better place for it, yes, but you would still have to call `clean()` in `save()` to make sure that your fields are valid at the time of instantiation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

Comment: Django separates validation from saving by design, and I don't agree that people should do validation within `save()`. It's not relevant to this specific question, though, so no need to debate it here.